# Is it possible to start a navigation drawer from the right corner or left corner?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

If I swipe from the right top corner towards middle of the screen a navigation drawer will be shown just like a page curl.
Please give some suggestions or links..

Comment: you can give the gravity accoridngly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this attribute in your drawer `ListView`:

```
android:layout_gravity="end"
```

and into your java file:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        } 
        else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```